# Is there a danger restricting a method to only be used on instances?

Tags: python, descriptor, python-descriptors

I want to restrict methods to be used on instance objects, not on class.  Does this break aspects of the data model, i.e. calls to `super()`?  Normally, the following works:

```py
class Foo:
    def bar(self, x=None):
         print(x)

Foo().bar(42)
Foo.bar(Foo(), 42)
```

I want to prevent the second case, because for some reason people make the mistake of calling `Foo.bar(42)`, which causes unanticipated errors that change as `bar` gets refactored (here it prints `None`).  Following the [tutorial on data descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods) I use the descriptor-decorator:

```py
from types import MethodType

class OnlyMethodNotUnboundFunction:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj is None:
            # Changed from `return self`
            raise UnboundLocalError("This method can only be used by an instantiated object, not a Class")
        return MethodType(self.func, obj)

class Foo():
    @OnlyMethodNotUnboundFunction
    def bar(self, x=None):
        print(x)
```

Now, `Foo().bar(42)` works as anticipated, but `Foo.bar(42)` raises the `UnboundLocalError`, as desired.  However, if I subclass `Foo` and call `super`, the behavior of the descriptor is not inherited in either call to super():

```py
class Baz1(Foo):
    def bar(self, x=None):
        super().bar(x)
        print(x + 1)

class Baz2(Foo):
    def bar(self, x=None):
        super(Baz2, self).bar(x)
        print(x + 1)
```

Both `Baz1.bar(Baz1(), 42)` and `Baz2.bar(Baz2(), 42)` print 42 and 43.  I had thought that the call to super() in `Baz1` would return the class `Foo`, not an instance.  The MRO would be the same in either case, but `Baz1.bar(Baz1(), 42)` should cause a call to `Foo.bar(42)` and raise the `UnboundLocalError`.

What's going on here?  Does `super()` detect the presence of a passed `self` argument and automatically return an instance?  Moreover, is there a way to inherit descriptors from parent class so that `Baz2.bar(Baz2(), 42)` also raises an error?

Comment: _Who_ is calling `Foo.bar(42)`, and why is that your problem?

Comment: I really don't understand what the use case is here... Methods should already only be called on  instances. That is the normal state of affairs.

Comment: Btw, I think `UnboundLocalError` is the wrong exception type to use in your descriptor

Comment: "I had thought that the call to super() in Baz1 would return the class Foo, not an instance." Calls to `super` will return neither of those, `super` **always** returns a. `super` object

Comment: It seems unnecessary to prevent people from doing the right thing -- `Foo.bar(Foo(), 42)` if they want to... I am surprised that `Foo.bar(42)` doesn't raise an exception. Is there a name for this behavior? Other OOP langauages would not allow this if bar() was not a static method (to use java/C# terminology). Or maybe it is merely that bar() is such a useless function that this "works" - self is None, and we print x which is also None, since it has a default value ... hmmmm

Comment: Yes seems also to me that in this case bar() should not be an instance method since it does not use instance values ...

Comment: @topsail calling a method on an object `instance.method(arg1, arg2)` is somewhat equivalent to the following in Python `type(instance).method(instance, arg1, arg2)`. That's why instance methods have `self` as the first argument and why you can call the method directly. In the OPs example, the function was called with `42` as the `self` argument and `x` as the default `None` so no exception was raised

Comment: Yes I see that now. Thank you.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I'm calling it because I'm refactoring and some tests or other parts of the library were written that call `Foo.bar(42)`.  This is an MWE, so in reality there are other arguments.  e.g. `def fit(self, x, y=None)` sets attributes and returns a value.  If its called as `Model.fit(x, y)` instead of `Model().fit(x, y)`, it may return the same value (based on shape of `y` instead of `x`) but add attributes to `x`.

Comment: Is the above really true? - would Model.fit() really do anything if it expects (needs!) an instance reference and doesn't get one (gets an array instead)? I would expect such a call to throw exceptions in real life.

Comment: @topsail in python, you can modify the attributes of objects dynamically, so I can add attributes to `self` without error even if it isn't the type of object I expect.  If it provides a useful result even when called incorrectly, it probably shouldn't be a method, but there's often two calling conventions I need to support: `m = Model(); m.fit(); m.transform()` as well as `Model().fit().transform()`.  Some models very much do store important state and need to be classes, but those that do not store important state still need to respect both calling conventions.

Comment: I guess I'm not convinced by the idea that such a method call would return a useful result. If I expected a model and I got back something else (an integer, or None) - not useful! Nor do I see how a method that requires an instance would be useful if called without an instance - sorry I don't see what you mean here.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think it should rise an `AttributeError`

Answer (score 3):

Your use case is "weird".
If someone calls `Foo.bar(Foo(), 42)`, fine, whatever,
they get what they deserve,
mostly they get hard-to-read code that is not idiomatic Python.

It *does* make sense to insist that 1st or 2nd parameter
passed in shall be of a certain type.
Use `instanceof( ... )`,
and `raise` a fatal error if caller messed up.
Feel free to enforce other [DbC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) preconditions
upon entry, such as requiring that some integer arg
shall be positive.
If you often see bad args passed in
then make the checks more stringent,
use more verbose names,
or improve the docs.

It also makes sense to help folks call you correctly,
enforced by the interpreter and also hinted at via IDEs.
So consider declaring the signature like this

```
def bar(self, *, x=None):
```

instead of

```
def bar(self, x=None):
```

That way you have an optional argument with a default,
but caller is forced to name the kwarg on every call,
reducing the chances for confusion.
(This works better if argument has a descriptive one-
or two-word name rather than just a single letter.)

Comment: `*` and `/` are good general advice, but maybe my MWE doesn't capture the full problem. The caller has written the contract, because a lot of scientific computing expects `model.fit(x, y=None)`.  In this case, scikit-learn's `Pipeline` object call's each step's `fit()` method on some data `x` (and optionally, `y`).  If I change the contract, I can't use `Pipeline`.

Answer (score 0):

First, the arguments in @J_H's answer are perfect - you really should not worry about this -

> If someone calls Foo.bar(Foo(), 42), fine, whatever, they get what they deserve, mostly they get hard-to-read code that is not idiomatic Python.

Second - instead of `UnboundLocalError` you really should raise `AttributeError` or `TypeError`: the former, although has "Unbound" in the name has to do with variable names. You can easily create a custom exception, inheriting from `AttributeError` that will make complete sense in your context:

```
class UnboundMethodError(AttributeError):
    pass
```

(that is all that is needed for a custom exeception that will be semantically ok)

And finally, past the point that "you should not", let's see "how to do it".

> What's going on here? Does super() detect the presence of a passed self argument and automatically return an instance?

As @juanpa.arrivilaga expressed: a `super()` call will return a `super`
object, which is a special type of proxy which will retrieve attributes as if they were from an instance. But that is irrelevant: if you write a method that takes `self` as a parameter: an instance already exists at that point.
In the idiom `Foo.bar` , bar is being retrieved from the class, but when the call is made to `Foo.bar(Foo(), ...)`, the method bar already gets the new `Foo()` instance as its self parameter.

The only way to propagate the behavior you create for your descriptor for overriden methods is using a mechanism to wrap these methods in your special descriptor as well.

This can be done at class creation time by using a special `__init_subclass__` method that will check if there are any overriden descriptors of the wanted type, and recreate them:

I modified your descriptor so that it does the `self` insertion manually, instead of creating a new `MethodType` on each invocation: it makes
`getattr`  on the class work correctly, which is needed in this approach.
(it is just that the method retrieved will error if it
was initially retrieved from the class, not an instance)

```
from types import MethodType

class OnlyMethodNotUnboundFunction:
    def __init__(self, func, instance=None):
        self.func = func
        self.instance = instance
        
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        return type(self)(func=self.func, instance=obj)
    
    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        if self.instance is None:
            raise AttributeError("This method can only be used by an instantiated object, not a Class")
        return self.func(self.instance, *args, **kw)

class Base:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(*args, **kwargs)
        for name, attr in list(cls.__dict__.items()):
            if not callable(attr):
                continue
            # temporarily remove method from the subclass so we can
            # inspect it at the superclass. delattr only removes the method
            # from the most derived subclass - in this case,  "cls"
            # With multiple inheritance, there is no other way
            # of retrieving the correct attribute without
            # reimplementing the C3 method resolution order
            # used by super(). (and super().attr does not work
            # for classes, just instances)
            delattr(cls, name)
            
            if isinstance(getattr(cls, name, None), OnlyMethodNotUnboundFunction):
                attr = OnlyMethodNotUnboundFunction(attr)
            # and restore it:
            setattr(cls, name, attr)
        
class Foo(Base):
    @OnlyMethodNotUnboundFunction
    def bar(self, x=None):
        print(x)
        
        
class Baz1(Foo):
    def bar(self, x=None):
        super().bar(x)
        print(x + 1)
```

And trying to use Baz1.bar, we get:

```
In [116]: Baz1().bar(10)
10
11

In [117]: Baz1.bar(Baz1(), 10)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
(...)
     14     return self.func(self.instance, *args, **kw)

AttributeError: This method can only be used by an instantiated object, not a Class
```